# How to fetch all row data from database using Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have records in a database with three different records in a particular column. I am trying to fetch all the records using Laravel but I am not getting it right after trying with multiple methods and each method is fetching only one record. I would be glad if I get assistance and to also learn from what I am not getting right. Thank you in advance.
Below is the code:

```
public function setBill()
{
    //With the below, I am getting only one record
    $FetchData = Students::all();
    foreach ($FetchData as $Data) {
        dd($Data->class);
    }
    //With this too, I am getting only one record
    $FetchData = Students::get();
    foreach ($FetchData as $Data) {
        dd($Data->class);
    }
    //With this as well, I am getting only one record
    $FetchData = DB::select('select * from students');
    foreach ($FetchData as $Data) {
        dd($Data->class);
    }
}
```

Comment: the first time the `dd` is called the script dies ("dump and die") ... if you don't want to end the script you can use `dump` instead

Comment: both dum and echo are displaying all records but I attempted to update a column in the table but all the data in the column are updated with one only one record fetched. I used this in the updating. $UpdateStudent          = Students::query()->update([
                    'term'=>$Term,
                    'bill_id'=>$Fetch->bill_id
                ]);

Comment: that would be updating the entire table since there was no conditions for what records to update

Comment: `Students::all()`  will grab all row from your `database`, try `count` it, `dd(count($FetchData))`

Comment: what database are you using?, can you show us your `Model`

Comment: This has solved my challenge: $UpdateData      = Model::where('column_name', '=', $request_data)->update([]);

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that `dd()` is stoping your script execution (dump and die).
If you want to see all fetched records you should do

```
$FetchData = Students::all();
dd($FetchData);
```

Otherwise, if you want to dump one record by one

```
$FetchData = Students::get();
foreach ($FetchData as $Data) {
     dump($Data->class);
}
```